# Printing booklet A6 format

Tags: printing, pdf, duplex-printing

With pdfbook2 it is possible to convert a pdf from A4 format to one which one can print onto A4 format, but then fold the pages in the middle and get a booklet of A5 format. I would like to go one step further, and reduce this to A6: Print on four pages onto one sheet of A4 paper, cut it in the middle, and then fold the resulting A5 paper to get a booklet of A6 size. pdfbook2 doesn't seem to have an option for this, running it twice does not produce the desired result, neither does printing the result with two pages per sheet of paper.

Comment: Does this reference from HP help? https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printers-Archive-Read-Only/How-to-print-an-A6-Booklet-Double-Sided-on-A4-paper/td-p/6043885

Comment: @User24601 Not that much. It describes a manual process of calculating which page of your pdf should go on which sheet of the paper to be printed, apparently with at least two of the same booklets in mind, as the same page is printed twice on the same sheet. I thought of only one copy, and wanted to automate the process. Anyway, it's interesting to see how they calculated things.